# Packer Docker Builder: configure shell for docker run?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, builder

i want to provision a docker image with docker and ansible. I want to use alpine as base image. Some docker images such as Alpine doesn't provide "/bin/bash". When packer runs that docker image it keeps starting /bin/bash. This will crash the build process:

dockerbuild.json:

```json
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "docker",
      "image": "alpine:3.8",
      "commit": true
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "user": "root",
      "playbook_file": "playbook.yml",
      "extra_arguments": [
        "--extra-vars",
        "ansible_connection=docker"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Error:

```
$> packer build dockerbuild.json
...
==> docker: Starting docker container...
    docker: Run command: docker run -v /Users/engi/.packer.d/tmp/packer-docker014300196:/packer-files -d -i -t alpine:3.8 /bin/bash
==> docker: Error running container: Docker exited with a non-zero exit status.
==> docker: Stderr: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I can run the image manually with "/bin/sh" or without explicit shell:

```
docker run --rm -i -t alpine:3.8 /bin/sh
docker run --rm -i -t alpine:3.8
```

Do you know how I can packer tell *not* to start /bin/bash ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at docs (surprise): **run_command**

https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker.html

This worked for me:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "docker",
      "image": "alpine:3.8",
      "commit": true,
      "run_command": ["-d", "-i", "-t", "{{.Image}}", "/bin/sh"]
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "ansible",
      "user": "root",
      "playbook_file": "playbook.yml",
      "extra_arguments": [
        "--extra-vars",
        "ansible_connection=docker"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```